# android, background resource turning black on ICS while working on KitKat

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a custom checkbox in round shape, on KitKat the buttons are rendered fine, but on ICS they are blacked when not selected. I define the style of buttons and drawables as below:

```
<style name="FilledCheckButton" parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox" >
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/v4_btn_weekday</item>
   <item name="android:button">@drawable/v4_btn_weekday</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

This is the v4_btn_weekday drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
<item android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:drawable="@drawable/filled_circle_green"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:drawable="@drawable/filled_circle_green"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:drawable="@drawable/filled_circle_green"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/v4_btn_radio_text_flat"
    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_circle_green" />
</selector>
```

And this is the empty_circle_green drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="#00a74f" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks.

These are the rendering:
- On KK, every unselected days look OK

[image: On KK]

- On ICS, unselected days black out

[image: On ICS]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set a background for the empty_circle_green drawable. Just add a solid with a transparent color and you will be fine.

Comment: can you be more specific, currently it is `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff00a74f" />
</shape>`. I already tried adding another transparent solid like this `    <solid android:color="#0000a74f" />`, still didn't work. Any tip?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say empty_circle_green. There you should add the transparent solid.

Comment: Thanks, already mark your answer. Can you edit it so others don't get confused. Tks.